# Calculating the distribution of random variables and the expected value/mean of a random variable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm not sure whether or not I picked the correct distribution method and calculated the distribution correctly. Here is the problem:

Consider Bob, an absent-minded student. Bob has a set of 5 passwords that he uses for all his login needs. He often forgets which password matches with which system so his strategy is to try all of them. Specifically, from his set of passwords he picks one uniformly at random and enters it. If he succeeds – all is well; if he fails – he removes the password from the set and repeats the process.

Suppose Bob switches to NotSoStrictSystem. This time around, this system will not limit the number of times a user tries to log in. Instead, if a user fails to enter the correct password for k consecutive times, it will delay its response by 2^k seconds. For example, if Bob gets the password right the first time, the delay is just 1 second, etc.

Let X(s) be equal to the delay in response with outcome, s. 
I got X(s) = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16}

a) For each such value i, what is P(X = i)?

For this, I treated this as a Bernoulli trial, since you can only have a success (correct password) or a failure (wrong password). I'm not sure whether to use the Binomial distribution or just calculate the distribution directly (sum of (X(s)*p(s) until s = 4). Anyways, this is my work:

P(x = 0) = C(5,0)*((2/5)^0)*(1-2/5)^(5-0) = ((3/5)^5) = (243/3125) 
P(x = 1) = C(5,1) * ((2/5)^1)*((1-2/5)^(5-1)) = 2*((3/5)^4) = 162/625 
P(x = 2) = C(5,2)*((2/5)^2) * (1-2/5)^(5-2) = 10*((2/5)^2)*((3/5)^3) = 216/625 
P(x = 3) = C(5,3)*((2/5)^3)*((1-2/5)^(5-3)) = 10((2/5)^3)*((3/5)^2) = 144/625 
P(x = 4) = C(5,4)*((2/5)^4)*((1-2/5)^(5-4)) = 5*((2/5)^4)*(3/5) = 48/625

b) What is E[X]?

For this, I used the distribution values from part b as p(s) and the X(s) values from above to get:

1(243/3125)+2(162/625)+4(216/625)+8(144/625)+16(48/625) = 15,783/3125 = E[X]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The probabilities are much simpler than the ones proposed. Let $Y$ be the number of trials until we get success. Then $Y=1,2,3,4,5$, each with probability $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: I got 2/5 for the probability. I'm just confused about whether or not I need to use Binomial distribution or regular distribution.

Comment: The right code is equally likely to be in positions $1$ to $5$. That's the easy way. Let's do it the hard way. The probability the first code works is obviously $\frac{1}{5}$. The probability the second code works is the probability the first doesn't, which is $\frac{4}{5}$, times the prob. the second works given the first doesn't. This is $\frac{1}{4}$ since we are discarding the first code. So prob. second works is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{5}$. Similar reasoning shows the probability the third is the right one is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{5}$. (Cont)

Comment: Similarly for the fourth, and now the fifth is obvious. But the easy way is easier! Binomial distribution has nothing to do with the problem.